# How to retrieve figures from a leveled data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

below is my table called "temp_table" in SQL, I want to get the data for the transaction no where column_3 is "CASH AED"

Current Data:

```
Transaction No       Column_1 Column_2 Column_3    Price
   1234               NULL      NULL   NULL         0
   1234                0        NULL   NULL         0
   1234               NULL      0      NULL         0
   1234               NULL      NULL   Cash AED     0
   1234               NULL      NULL   NULL         0    
   1234               NULL      NULL   NULL         15
   1234               NULL      NULL   NULL         0
   1234               NULL      NULL   Cash AED     0
   1234               NULL      NULL   NULL         0    
   1234               NULL      NULL   NULL         0
   1234               NULL      NULL   NULL         0
   1222               NULL      NULL   NULL         0 
   1222                0        NULL   NULL         0
   1222               NULL      0      NULL         0
   1222               NULL      NULL   Cash AED     0
   1222               NULL      NULL   NULL         0    
   1222               NULL      NULL   NULL         25
   1222               NULL      NULL   NULL         0
   1222               NULL      NULL   Cash AED     0
   1222               NULL      NULL   NULL         0    
   1222               NULL      NULL   NULL         0
   1222               NULL      NULL   NULL         0
```

Desired Output:

```
Transaction No        Column_3   Price
   1234               Cash AED   15
   1222               Cash AED   25
```

Keeping in mind for the same transaction, in the column_3 the value "Cash AED" is repeated.

Comment: I gave an answer that should return what you want, but a little bit more explanation of the logic would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . .

```
select distinct transaction_no, column_3
from t
where column_3 = 'Cash AED';
```

Is that really what you want?

EDIT:

With `price`, you can use aggregation:

```
select transaction_no, column_3, max(price) as price
from t
where column_3 = 'Cash AED'
group by transaction_no, column_3;
```

This works for the data you have provided.

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end

Comment: @KobyDouek . . . Why?  The use of semicolons as statement terminators is a best practice.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, sorry for some reason the price column was not appearing in my question, I have edited now

Answer (score 1):

Use DISTINCT SELECT clause :

```
  SELECT DISTINCT TransactionNo , Column_3
  FROM yourtableName
  WHERE Column_3 = 'Cash AED'
```

Comment: sorry for some reason the price column was not appearing in my question, I have edited now

Answer (score 1):

The description is not completely clear, but this should give the desired output:

```
SELECT [Transaction No], MAX(Column_3) AS Column_3, MAX(Price) AS Price
FROM temp_table GROUP BY [Transaction No] ORDER BY [Transaction No]
```